# .htaccess file / hide subdirectory

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess

I tried several solutions found on StackOverflow but none of them seem to work.
First, on document root, I have *.htaccess file* and *index.php* that detects language and redirect on `/fr/` directory or `/en/` directory.
Then I have *index.html* file and a directory called "pages" in which they are all my pages. In that way, all urls are like http://example.com/fr/index.html or http://example.com/fr/pages/a.html.

I would like to :

1. Hide "**index.html**". If I'm not mistaken, this solution is
   fine :

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Hide **html** and **php** extension. I used this and it worked
   fine for php but not html...don't know why.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
   ```
3. Hide pages directory (i don't mind if /fr/ or /en/ directories
   are shown) so that URL will be like this (in the end) : http://example.com/fr/a

Here is my structure

```
├── fr
|   └── index.html
|   └── pages
|       └──a.html
|       └──b.html etc
├── en
|   └── index.html
|   └── pages
|       └──a.html
|       └──b.html etc
├── .htaccess
└── index.php
```

Comment: what is the use of `index.php` it seems the servers only sees `index.php` and not `index.html`

Comment: you will have to put your action manually, try `RewriteRule  ^/fr/a/?$   fr/a.html   [NC,L]` you redirection link will be example.com/fr/a may be that will do the magic for you

Comment: Is your "site structure" complete? If it is then there is no need to "hide the php extension" - because you don't have any!? Also, are `a.html`, `b.html` etc. really single character basenames (as in your example)? If they are then the directives can be simplified further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Hide "index.html". If I'm not mistaken, this solution is fine :
>
>    ```
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
>    ```

You say "fine", however, this does not appear to correlate with your site structure, so it wouldn't appear to do anything? This directive assumes you have `index.html` in the document root. But don't you want to remove `index.html` and `index.php` regardless of where they appear in the URL-path? For example, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(html|php)
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(html|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The condition is to prevent a redirect loop on certain server configs.

This also requires that both `index.php` and `index.html` are included in your `DirectoryIndex.`

> 2. Hide html and php extension. I used this and it worked fine for php but not html...don't know why.
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L] 
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
>    ```

This is a *conflict*. You have the same `RewriteRule` *pattern* - so which should "win"? The first directive will always "win", the second directive will never happen.

But... is your "site structure" not complete? Your site structure shows a single `index.php` in the document root (which is redirected to `/` anyway) - there are no `.php` files in subdirectories, so why the need to check?

If you do have a mix of `.html` and `.php` files throughout your site structure, with no discernible pattern then you will need to perform a filesystem check to see if the file exists before rewriting to it (which is relatively expensive). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

There is no need to backslash-escape a dot (to match a literal dot) when used inside a character class, as it carries no special meaning when used inside the character class (as opposed to elsewhere in the regex).

However, if there is a *pattern*, then this can be greatly improved.

> 3. Hide pages directory (I don't mind if `/fr/` or `/en/` directories are shown) so that URL will be like this (in the end) : `http://example.com/fr/a`

To clarify, you must first link to `example.com/fr/a`.

Then to rewrite all requests to the `/pages` subdirectory (and append the `.html` extension in the same motion), you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/pages/$2.html [L]
```

Comment: Yes my structure is not complete. I forgot to mention that in `/pages/` directory there is a php file (`contact.php`), which is present in both `/fr/` and `/en/`. Sorry. 
That's why i need the Rewrite rule for php documents.
Index.php is just here to detect if the visitor is french-speaking or english-speaking, then it redirects in the right directory.

Thank you for you answer, the rewrite rule for pages is perfect, i just can't display my `contact.php` page. Don't know why...

Comment: In fact i know why, it's trying to reach `/pages/contact.html` and not `/contact`

Comment: I just remove the .html extension from the Rewrite pages rule and now all is working. Thanks !

Comment: @MrWhite That's an explanation very useful.